# Why am I getting 'Syntax error on token ">", invalid FunctionExpressionHeader'

Tags: jquery

Code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            navegadorNotificacionesActivas = navigator.indigitall.notificationsActive();
            if(navegadorNotificacionesActivas){
                navigator.indigitall.getStatus(
                        (status) => {
                            if (status == "enabled") {
                                document.getElementById("myCheck").cheked = true;
                              } else {
                                  document.getElementById("myCheck").cheked = false;                                  
                            }
                        }, ""/*errorCallback*/);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("myCheck").cheked = false;
            }

        });
```

At line 5 I am getting the

> 'Syntax error on token ">", invalid FunctionExpressionHeader'

But I thought that this was a valid statement. I'm trying no to write the function in a separated statement, but asi I will use it only once, in the call to the succescallback method.

```
navigator.indigitall.getStatus(successCallBack, errorCallBack)
```

Comment: Could it be be a problem with some invisible character? Sounds possible?

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 is `(status) => {`, isn't it?

Do you have ES6 activated ?

Comment: Yep, that's the line. Dunno what version of JS they are using, how could I check?